# firebase database error when run app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I try to connect my app to firebase database to  receiving a list of data from firebase displayed using recyclerview and cardview, but there are many errors when add Dependencies
I get this error when run app .

The first mistake -

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/iid/zzc.class
```

this my app build gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.seu.hh.mm"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'

}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

this my build gradle project

```
 allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
}

   }

   buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

please help me :(
how can solve this problem  and make app run

Comment: don't abuse **bold**s (`**`)

Comment: use last version of firebase version 11.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'` with `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'` and that's why you have a duplicate.

So first off all you need to remove this line of code:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'
```

Change this lines of code:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

In this way you'll have the lates versions.